# Scheduled rules execute a hour after they are supposed to

Tags: cron, rules

I have created a scheduled rule that sends a email based on a date field in nodes of a certain content type. The rule executes as scheduled and the email is sent but for some reason it only fires exactly a hour after its supposed to.

E.g on the admin/config/workflow/rules/schedule page the item is scheduled to execute at Thu, 2017-08-03 15:30 but I only receive the email at 16:30.

I could fix this by adding a offset to the trigger time but I would rather want to understand why this is happening and fix the problem accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

#### Cause 1:

After a rule is scheduled (using the Rules Scheduler submodule), it will only actually *execute* **next time cron runs**. Example:

- schedule a rule to execute at `timestamp X`.
- if the next time that cron runs is at `Y mins after timestamp X`, then the Rules execution will only happen then (= at `Y mins after timestamp X`).

#### Cause 2:

If your site is set to the correct timezone, but your users are set to a timezone that is 1 hour ahead, then that might also explain what's happening. In that case, correct the timezone accordingly.

Comment: To add to this answer, you should consider using [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) as this will allow you to run specific cron tasks at different time intervals rather than using the default Drupal Core cron, which runs **all** cron tasks every x hours.

Comment: @NoSssweat good point! why not convert your comment to an extra answer (gives you way more space to elaborate on it also) ...

Comment: Thanks for the invite, but I think this is fine.